# Why creating different object from same package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I just learned something from [this site](https://analyticsindiamag.com/data-pre-processing-in-python/). I do not understand that in the post the writer create 2 standard scaler object `sc_X = StandardScaler()` and `sc_y = StandardScaler()`, assigning same `Standard Scaler` to two different variables `sc_X` and `sc_y` and use **each** for `X` and `y` **separately**. While previous line he creates `le_X = LabelEncoder()` assigning `LabelEncoder()` to one variable `le_X` to be used on **both** `X` and `y`. I do not understand why he creates two variables for same function to be used separately on ***each** `X` and `y` and then create one variable to be used for **both** `X` and `y`. I'm so confused right now. Please someone explain why is it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) don't need to extract information from the data to work, this program just run on the series and transform the target values in numbers.

The [StandardScale](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) compute mean and variance of the column to scale them.

Seen this, the x and y column may have 2 different mean and standard deviation, needing to be computed separately and that is why they created 2 objects.

Comment: Note, the LabelEncoder save a vector with all names. That means that if you encoder a column and encoder another column that column have the old mapping and a new mapping. It's good to work separately with all that.